# How to make Polygon described by the streets crossroads (LineString intersections) in geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, gis, shapely, geopandas

I have downloaded geojson data for 4 different streets as LineString objects. I read them via geopandas and I have 4 different GeoDataFrames. Here they are after using union method: 
[image: four streets as crossing linestrings]

However, I would like to have ONLY the Polygon that is described by the crossroads of the streets, something like this:

[image: four streets as polygon]

How I can do this in geopandas/python?

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: Sure!
1) https://pastebin.com/KcUZZkp9
2) https://pastebin.com/sAtXvbjx
3) https://pastebin.com/M09xL466
4) https://pastebin.com/PYDb7k6p

this is in raw geojson format